# Apache mod_alias / .htaccess, headers different on RedirectMatch vs RewriteRule

Tags: apache2, url-rewriting, mod-alias

Do you have any idee why the Authorization header is lost when using

> RedirectMatch .*service_auth /service/

vs

> RewriteEngine on RewriteRule ^(.*service_auth)$ /service/ [QSA]

With the first one I get

```
   'User-Agent' => 'Jakarta Commons-HttpClient/3.1',
   'Authorization' => 'Basic dGhlZHJpdmVyaXM6555udXByZQ==',
   'Host' => 'admin.mysite.uat'
```

and from the second

```
   'User-Agent' => 'Jakarta Commons-HttpClient/3.1',
   'Host' => 'admin.mysite.uat'
```

Thanks